# htaccess from subdomain www to domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a link that i need to have a 301 redirect from
www.subdirectory.domain.com to http://subdirectory.domain.com

Ive seen plenty of combinations but am unsure how to achieve this

Not sure if something like this works but i get an error

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(subdirectory)\.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%subdirectory.domain.com/$1 [L,R,301]
```

Comment: You should post the error message with your question, as that makes it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with your rewrite:

First, you need to remove the `%` from `%subdirectory.domain.com`, since it's not part of your domain name and is probably not a valid character for domain names.

Second, the redirect flag should be `R=301` instead of `R,301` — I'd guess that's  what's giving you the error.

Other than those things, your rewrite should work.